# Formatting quotes from the fortune to use it with conky

Tags: text-processing, scripting, conky

I'm using [fortune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_%28Unix%29) cookie outputs in my conky script.
My  [fortune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_%28Unix%29) output is in the  following format:

> **Text1** : Some message including( line break 
>  tags, e.g. and comma(,),=,semicolon(;) like symbols)

Is it possible separate Text1 & Message(
 and semicolon(;) are used to separate lines)?
Also can I render html tags in a conky script?
I'm looking for some inline script (sed,awk or some built-in alternative) which I can readily use in the conky script.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more concise ways, but Text1 and Message can be separated onto separate lines, and ';'s used as line break markers, by piping the fortune output through a couple of sed substitutions, such as

```
sed 's/ : / :\n/' | sed 's/; /\n/'g
```

So, a fortune output such as

> Text1 : Blah blah; bleh blah blah; meh meh meh.

will be output as

> Text1 :
> Blah blah
> bleh blah blah
> meh meh meh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but if you are trying to replace "Text1", "Message(" and ";" with newlines you can pipe through `sed 's/Text1/\n/;s/Message[(]/\n/;s/;/\n/'`

Answer (score 0):

**Random cows with fortune in `conky` `.conkyrc`**

```
${voffset -1}${hr .25}
${execi 120 fortune -s | fold -w20 | cowsay -f $(ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows/ | shuf -n1)}
```

This `-w20` can be changed to whatever cut off point you want in characters.